# Sorting results in Advanced System Reporter in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore's [Advanced System Reporter](http://trac.sitecore.net/AdvancedSystemReporter/) (v1.3) shared source module, is there an out-of-the-box way of sorting the results before the results are displayed to email/screen or will I need to implement something myself?

In a standard ASR install, I can see the *Media Viewer* viewer configuration item has a *sort* parameter in the attributes field but it's using *ASR.Reports.Items.ItemViewer* class which, after checking in reflector, doesn't respect the *sort* parameter. I take this to mean that the class might have respected the sort parameter previously but doesn't now.

As a side thought, I would have thought that a Scanner class would be a much more logical place to put sorting logic than at the Viewer class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. The sort parameter I found is actually used when running the report by the ASR module.

The sort parameter is set up in the attributes and is in the following format:

```
sort=ColumnName,ASC|DESC,[DateTime]
```

where Column Name is the display name of the column, ASC or DESC is the sort direction and is required and DateTime is to be set if the column is a date time value.

Example:
Given the column formatting of

```
<Columns>
  <Column name="item name">Item Name</Column>
  <Column name="publish date">Publish Date</Column>
</Columns>
```

to sort by publish date descending, the appropriate sort parameter would be

```
sort=Publish Date,DESC,DateTime
```

and to sort by item name, the sort parameter would be

```
sort=Item Name,ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anyone can answer your question immediately, apart from probably the module author. But you have a huge advantage in this case - the module sources. Instead of browsing the assemblies with the Reflector, you can check out the latest sources and just debug it. One debug session can answer more questions than a bunch of SO posts. ;-)

Also, as a side note, you might have noticed special Sitecore logos on that page - [this blog post](http://sharesitecore.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/announcing-the-better-shared-source-initiative/) will tell you what it means.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was my impression that this was a widely used module and I was expecting sorting of results to be quite widely used. I was hoping that it was a simple answer and I was just missing something. I will do the debugging session as you suggest and see if that provides me with anything useful.